# Boost.Log to file and stdout simultaneously?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I've used `boost::log` successfully to log to stdout (using the `TRIVIAL` macros) **or** to log to a file (basically following the steps in the tutorial).

How would we configure to log to a file **and** stdout simultaneously?

This is a common use case in our setup when we want to have both, a log file and also all the output that goes to the log on the console.

Any input appreciated!

Comment: have you tried reading [this documentation](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/sinks.html)? It says `You can register more than one sink. Each sink will receive and process log records as you emit them independently from others.
`

Comment: @nurettin Yep, but how do you register sinks for output to stdout? Couldn't find that (yet..)

Comment: add_stream( boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream>(&std::cout, empty_deleter() ) ); // ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As per [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/log/doc/html/index.html) you can simply use the [`add_console_log()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/add_console_lo_idp21543664.html) convenience function like so:

```
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>

logging::add_console_log(std::cout, boost::log::keywords::format = ">> %Message%");
```

Of course you can always dig into the sink configuration manually as indicated by some of the comments.